# Append a value to list only if it has not occurred previously

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings. I am trying to append the values to a new list but, only those values which are not consecutive.

like for example,

If i have a list like this,

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

I need output like

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
print([k for k, _ in groupby(data)])
# --> ['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: I ran this through `timeit` and it is also the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip_longest` from `itertools` and compare with the next element in the list:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']

b = [i for i,j in zip_longest(a,a[1:]) if i!=j]
print(b)
```